# How to deploy Ruby on rails app using Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bamboo

I wish to automated building, testing, deploying and releasing of rails app.

is there any way to make it ?

Answer (score 5):

Mark Wolfe's excellent [Bamboo Ruby Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/au.id.wolfe.bamboo.rake-bamboo-plugin) (GitHub: [rake-bamboo-plugin](https://github.com/wolfeidau/rake-bamboo-plugin/)) *enables you to run ruby tasks during a build in Bamboo* and includes tasks for the most prevalent Ruby build, test and automation tools, e.g.:

- [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) - *maintains a consistent environment for ruby applications*
- [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) - *simple ruby build program with capabilities similar to make*
- [Capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com/) - *remote server automation and deployment tool*
- [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) - *testing tool for the Ruby programming language*
- [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) - *executes plain-text functional descriptions as automated tests*

Please note that there's also the [Bamboozled Ruby Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.alienfast.bamboozled.ruby.bamboozled-ruby-plugin), which is a fork from Mark's rake-bamboo-plugin version 2.1 with the goal to *move the plugin forward in a specific way* - I haven't used it so far, thus can't comment on the differences, please refer to their [GitHub: bamboozled-ruby-plugin](https://github.com/alienfast/bamboozled-ruby-plugin) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but mostly by scripting.

There is a type of Bamboo task simply called "script". We use for our Perl/Python code base. It requires more work than what you have to do with all the Java tools, but it is still worth it.

Then, for instance, if you produce a JUnit-compatible XML test result, Bamboo will very nicely interpret it for you.